# Linked List function in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm taking an online course and when the instructor executes this code it works, but it doesnt when I try to execute it on DevC++. And I cannot understand why. It's basically supposed to add a value to the linked list based on its order. I'd really appreciate your help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct n{
    int x;
    struct n * next;   
} node;

void print(node *r){
    int count=0;
    while(r->next != NULL){
        printf("%d-ci eleman= %d \n", count, r->x);
        r=r->next;
        count++;
    }
    
}
node* siraliek(node *r, int x){
    if(r==NULL){ //if the linked list is empty
        r=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        r->next=NULL;
        r->x = x;
        return r;
    }
    node * iter =r;
    
    while(iter->next !=NULL && iter->next->x < x){
        iter= iter->next;
    }
    if(r->x >x){//if the added value is smaller than the previous value in linked list
        node*temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->x = x;
        temp->next = r;
        return temp;
    }
    node* temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->next = iter->next;
    iter -> next = temp;
    temp ->x = x;
    
}

int main(){
    node*temp = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    node * root;
    root = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    root=NULL;
    root =siraliek(root, 200);
    root=siraliek(root, 25);
    root=siraliek(root, 20);
    root=siraliek(root, 300);

    node * iter;
    iter=root;
    print(root);
}
```

Comment: Well, this code is incomplete as posted.

Comment: Where is  node structure?

Comment: I did not think I had to post the structure or the include statements since they're the obvious parts but yeah let me update it

Comment: What precisely you mean by "doesn't" (work)?

Comment: Inside structure there can be various different variables so it is not obvious

Comment: @FredLarson terminal shows that my code worked, but it does not print anything.

Comment: @Victor I've updated, so it should be more clear now

Comment: Why set `root` to `NULL` right after you `malloc` it? That's a certain memory leak.

Comment: @FredLarson so you mean that I should set the 'NEXT' of 'root' to 'NULL'? I also tried that but the same outcome again.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how that thing is working, certainly not very well. I suspect [something like this](https://godbolt.org/z/3bc64Tboz) was what was intended. (more or less).

Comment: @WhozCraig that is exactly what was intended. But why doesn't it work on my compiler tho?

Comment: @MahmutMahmudov  It seems your instructor is overqualified.:)

Comment: If your instructor gave that code a pass they're smoking crack. Besides some of the basic logic errors already noted, there are some dreadful ones. [See these?](https://godbolt.org/z/vE1eo8qos) That "control reached end of non-void function" for function `siraliek` is a blueprint for *undefined behavior*, especially considering that non-specified return value is reaped repeatedly in `main`. Note, btw, the code I linked earlier is pure C. It will *not* compile with a C++ toolchain due to how `malloc` is used.

Comment: Both `iter` and `temp` in `main()` seem to be superfluous, especially `temp` which has memory allocated for it but it isn't used.  And the sequence: `node * root; root = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node)); root=NULL;` just leaks memory — bad, bad, bad!  Is your instructor actually qualified to teach this course?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will be able to find an answer to your problem using this file that I have written. It has a variety of functions that do operations with linked lists. In the main program I have included an example where I insert some numbers and than do the sorting. Please do not hesitate if you have any questions concerning the code!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
} node;

// Prints a string of characters.
static inline void print(const char* f, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, f);
    vprintf(f, args);
    va_end(args);
}

// Prints a string of characters followed by a new line.
static inline void println(const char* f, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, f);
    vprintf(f, args);
    va_end(args);
    printf("\n");
}

static inline void* mem_alloc(size_t size)
{
    void* p = malloc(size);

    if (p == NULL)
    {
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "Problem with malloc().");
    }
    return p;
}



// Verify if node is empty 
int node_is_empty(node * head)
{
    return head == NULL;
}

// Verify if node is not empty 
int node_is_not_empty(node * head)
{
    return head != NULL;
}

//Builds the sentinell of the node structure

node* node_build_sentinel()
{
    // Creates the sentinel.
    node* head = mem_alloc(sizeof(node));
    head->value = 0;
    head->next = NULL;


    // Returns the head of the node which is the sentinell.
    return head;
}

//Prints the contents of a node 
void node_print(node* head)
{
    print("{");
    while(head->next)
    {
        head = head->next;
        print(" %d", head->value);
    }
    println(" }");
}

//Frees the allocated node
void node_free(node* head)
{
    node* previous;

    while (head)
    {
        previous = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(previous);
    }
}

// Inserts a value right after the head
/*

    HEAD -> 1 -> 2 -> ..... -> 8 
    node_insert_beg(node* HEAD, int 42);
    HEAD -> 42 -> 1 -> 2 -> ..... -> 8

*/
void node_insert_beg(node* head, int value)
{
    node* tmp = mem_alloc(sizeof(node));
    tmp->value = value;
    tmp->next = head->next;
    head->next = tmp;
}

// Inserts a value right after the head
/*

    HEAD -> 1 -> 2 -> ..... -> 8 
    node_insert_end(node* HEAD, int 42);
    HEAD -> 1 -> 2 -> ..... -> 8 -> 42

*/
void node_insert_end(node* head, int value)
{
    node* tmp = mem_alloc(sizeof(node));
    for (; node_is_not_empty(head->next); head = head->next)
    {
        //This loop runs to the last node and quits with head being that last node
        continue;
    }
    tmp->value = value;
    tmp->next = head->next;
    head->next = tmp;
}

//Inserts odd values to the end and even values to the beginning
void node_insert_num_odd_and_even(node* head, int value)
{
    //odd
    if(value % 2)
    {
        node_insert_end(head, value);
    }
    //even
    else
    {
        node_insert_beg(head, value);
    }
}


//Extracts the minimum value of the node (in other words deletes it from the node)
void node_extract_min(node* list,node *sup)
{
    node *before_min = list;
    while (list->next != NULL)
    {
        if (list->next->value < before_min->next->value)
        {
            before_min = list;
        }   
        list = list->next;
    }
    node *output = before_min->next;
    before_min->next = before_min->next->next;
    output->next = NULL;
    while (sup->next!=NULL)
    {
        sup = sup->next;
    }
    sup->next = output;
}


//Extracts the maximum value of the node (in other words deletes it from the node)
void node_extract_max(node* list, node* sup)
{
    node *before_max = list;
    while (list->next != NULL)
    {
        if (list->next->value > before_max->next->value)
        {
            before_max = list;
        }   
        list = list->next;
    }
    node *output = before_max->next;
    before_max->next = before_max->next->next;
    output->next = NULL;
    while (sup->next!=NULL)
    {
        sup = sup->next;
    }
    sup->next = output;
}

//Inserts a node into a SORTED linked list
void node_insert_sort(node * head, int value)
{
    node* tmp = mem_alloc(sizeof(node));
    tmp->value = value;
    //Run through the nodes until it is not empty and the value of the next node is smaller than value parameter
    for (; node_is_not_empty(head->next) && (head->next->value >= value); head = head->next)
    {
        continue;
    }
    tmp->next = head->next;
    head->next = tmp;
}

//Sorts any linked list from largest values to the smallest
void node_sort_linked_list(node * head)
{
    //Linear sort, find max and swap it with the first val

    //If there is only a sentinel
    if ( node_is_empty(head->next) )
    {
        //Do nothing since there is only a sentinel
    }
    else
    {
        node * tmp;
        tmp = node_build_sentinel();
        while (node_is_not_empty(head->next))
        {
            node_extract_max(head,tmp);
        }
        head->next = tmp->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
}


//Deletes the first occurence of value in node
int node_delete_first_occurence(node* head, node* sup, int value)
{
    int seen = 0;
    node *tmp = head;
    while (head->next != NULL)
    {
        if (head->next->value == value)
        {
            tmp = head;
            seen+=1;
            break;
        }   
        head = head->next;
    }
    if(seen == 0)
    {
        return seen;
    }
    node *output = head->next;
    tmp->next = tmp->next->next;
    output->next = NULL;
    while (sup->next!=NULL)
    {
        sup = sup->next;
    }
    sup->next = output;
    return seen;
}

//Deletes all occurences of value in node
int node_delete_all_occurences(node* head, node* sup, int value)
{
    int seen = 0;
    node *tmp = head;
    while (head->next != NULL)
    {
        if (head->next->value == value)
        {
            seen+=1;
            tmp = head;
            node *output = head->next;
            tmp->next = tmp->next->next;
            output->next = NULL;
            while (sup->next!=NULL)
            {
                sup = sup->next;
            }
            sup->next = output;
            continue;
        } 
        head = head->next;
    }
    return seen;
}

//Get a node at index if index invalid return NULL
//DOES NOT DELETE THE NODE
node * node_get_at(node* node, unsigned long index)
{
    while (node != NULL && index > 0)
    {
        node = node->next;
        index--;
    }
    if (node != NULL)
    {
        node = node->next;
    }
    return node;
}

//Gets the sum of all the values in the nodes
int* node_sum(node * head)
{
    int * sum_elem = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
    int sum = 0;
    int elements = 0;
    while (head->next != NULL)
    {
        elements+=1;
        sum += head->next->value;
        head = head->next;
    }
    sum_elem[0] = sum;
    sum_elem[1] = elements;
    return sum_elem;
}


int main()
{
    node * nodes = node_build_sentinel();

    node_insert_end(nodes,3);

    node_insert_end(nodes,1);

    node_insert_end(nodes,9);

    node_insert_end(nodes,45);

    node_insert_end(nodes,-4);

    node_sort_linked_list(nodes);

    node_print(nodes);

    node_free(nodes);
    return 0;
}
```